# nothing comes up when i go to my website.com/wp-admin? Which files should I look for?

Tags: wp-admin

My hosting company (godaddy) tells me that someone has hacked my wordpress admin login and have put garbage on filesystem. My website is down. and nothing comes up when i try to get my files using mywebsite.com/wp-admin (which I use to manage my files). I am not an expert and had got the site done from outside agency.

Comment: nothing comes up means what ? blank page ? error ?

Comment: Its blank page. Tried both on firefox and safari browser. Have a mac so dont have IE.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't break my mind about which files are exactly mandatory to be replaced. Just replace `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` — if he just had access to your wordpress administration I would make sure to check all of the theme and plugins files which are *accessible* through the *administration panel*  if he included `base64` malware code and look-a-like. There are plugins for novice users (no shame) to check for such things - [this post at WPMU.org](http://wpmu.org/why-you-should-never-search-for-free-wordpress-themes-in-google-or-anywhere-else/) goes over free themes which isn't interesting in your case, however they cover what tools you may use in such a scenario.

[Here's the Wordpress Codex Files list](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Files) which gives you a good overview which files do what, what they control, what they're needed for and so on.

Some links to similar issues (blank/white page):

- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/blank-page-on-wp-admin
- http://www.nerdfrat.com/how-to-fix-a-wp-admin-blank-page (advanced)

Comment: Well it does not make lot of sense. Cause the timestamps on any of the files or folders are older (not matching with since the time the site is down which is just a week ago). to be precise it www.ptsol.com/wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy is usually pretty helpful when it comes to this sort of thing. You should be able to manage all of your wordpress login settings etc... through your godaddy account. Have you spoken to godaddy support?

Comment: I did..They said they cant control the contents once logged in via wordpress admin access. Is there anything specific I should be asking them?

Comment: Can you access your site via ftp? That would be something that they could definitely help you with. Tell them you would like to be able to access your site files with filezilla. Once you're in, you can at least back up all of your stuff to your computer, then you will be in a position to figure out how to get wordpress working again.

Comment: Yes I can and I can definitely back it up. However, I was thinking of getting the corrupted/infected files out first so I can get wp-admin and my website up and running and then backup clean copy.

Comment: Which are the minimum files that are required to login successfully on wp-admin? Cleaning which files can give me access to wp-admin?

Comment: So just to confirm, you can access the site files via ftp using filezilla?

Answer (score 0):

To all the folks who get this kind of error a must check option.
turn on error reporting if you have commented the lines in your `wp-config.php`

```
@ini_set('display_errors','Off');
```

and than check for error.
if it has the error like this

```
PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /[server info]/wp-config.php:77)
```

than check your  `wp-config.php` for extra space at top and bottom of the page.remove extra line spaces even. and than re-upload the `wp-config.php`.
Most of time this will solve your problem.

Happy Coding!!!!